# IIS 7 Redirecting Default Website to custom page

Tags: iis, iis-7, webserver, windows-server-2008

We have a website that is setup on IIS 7 and are trying to replace it with a new site.

The old site used a custom file as the homepage, called WN-main.asp

The new site is no longer using ASP, and we'd like to use a regular index.html as the main file.  However, when we go to the website, it keeps trying to redirect our .com to .com/WN-main.asp

In the IIS "Default Document" settings we have index.html at the top, and WN-main.asp is nowhere to be found in the list (it never was there).  Where on earth in IIS is this redirect sitting?  :)

We've also removed the web.config file from the root directory, and put the entire old website in a subdirectory.  As well as restarted IIS.  Any ideas where this redirect is sitting?

Thanks!

Comment: To view the actual error, you can go to http://www.worzalla.com right now, though soon we will have to put the old ASP site back up.

Comment: hey I am getting 404 error for this link now. Is this resolved?

Comment: @Kim L When I go to worzalla.com I see a really nice webpage. I really envy your styling and look and feel. I get no re-direct.  When I go to worzalla.com/wn-main.asp I get a 404 error. Is it just some obscure cache on the server that has finally cleared?

Comment: Thanks!  We are not sure exactly what ended up being the issue - somewhere, somehow, the old homepage was possibly cached on the server and the page itself had a redirect to the /WN-main.asp page...even though the server should not have been caching anything.  After playing around with multiple things, it just suddenly started working!  Grrr Microsoft.

Comment: (We did also disable and re-enable asp and .net though - which may have helped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not sure exactly what ended up being the issue - somewhere, somehow, the old homepage was possibly cached on the server and the page itself had a redirect to the /WN-main.asp page...even though the server should not have been caching anything and we had checked that multiple times initially. After playing around with lots of settings, it just suddenly started working! Grrr Microsoft. The fact that we disabled and enabled asp and .net may have helped, but I'm not sure...at least it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, you can configure settings to other levels than the website, e.g. a machine.config file which defines settings for all sites of a server. The final configuration for your site will not only use your web.config, but also these other parent level configurations.

Check these files to see if any define this wrong `<defaultDocument>`:

```
Server-level configuration is stored in the following configuration files:    
- Machine.config. This file is located in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG.    
- Root Web.config for the .NET Framework. This file is located in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG.    
- ApplicationHost.config. This file is located in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config.

Site, application, and virtual and physical directory configuration can be stored in one of the following locations:    
- A server-level configuration file. When configuration for a site, application, directory, or URL is stored in a server-level configuration file, you must use a location tag to specify the site, application, directory, or URL to which the configuration applies.    
- A parent-level Web.config file. When configuration for an application, directory, or URL is stored in a parent-level configuration file, you must use a location tag to specify the child at which the configuration applies.     
- The Web.config file for the site, the application, or the directory. When you configure settings for an application, directory, or URL, the configuration is stored in the same directory as the site, application, or directory. You do not need to use location tags.
```

Extracted from: [Working with configuration files in IIS7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)